# phpMyAdmin File Could Not Be Read

Tags: mysql, php, centos

Whenever I try to upload a file to import into phpMyAdmin I get the following error:

> File could not be read

phpMyAdmin is the only php script I am running on my server, and as such my php configuration file is fairly vanilla except for the following changes:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 50M
memory_limit = 64M
```

The file I am trying to import is 4MB, well within the 10MB upload size and 50MB post size (it is also UTF-8). Setting upload_tmp_dir actually fixed a previous problem I was having (where phpMyAdmin was complaining that I didn't even specify a file) or at least made the error change to what I am getting now. The permissions on /tmp are 777.

What could the problem be? The file comes from a cpanel installation at hostmonster I am migrating away from onto my own vps. I have tried getting the sql file from the cpanel backup utility and from their installation of phpMyAdmin (both uncompressed and gzipped). I do not believe that the files are corrupted.

Extra information: I am running CentOS 5.6, phpMyAdmin 3.4.2, mysql 5.1.52, and php 5.2.16.

Comment: Are the web server error logs showing anything that could give you more of a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Just to make sure I set the log to a new file and tried the upload. The only entries in the new file pertain to my self signed ssl certificate. The SSL is actually something I added in after I was already getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `open_basedir` is set in your php.ini PHP will not be able access files above that directory.

Comment: Aha! I had open_basedir set to `/var/www/vhosts`. I changed it to `/var/www` and set up a temp directory there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is setting of `php.ini`:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
open_basedir = /data/home/:/tmp/
```

The `open_basedir` needs add the `/tmp/` too

Answer (score 1):

I think you can setup this in the configuration file php.ini:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
open_basedir = /var/www:/data/home:/tmp
```

But, don't add the last slash of the targeted directories. Founded in the php documentation :

```
When you want to restrict access to only the specified directory, end with a slash. For example: open_basedir = /dir/incl/
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php